# how to pass a value to running process in python

Tags: python, subprocess, threadpool

I want to pass some values to a running process, how can I do that ?

say for example I have a worker.py and it has this code.

```
import os
import sys

def my_test():
    print " I am starting now"
    a = raw_input("Do you want to start ? ")[0].lower()
    if a == "y":
        print "Yes I am starting now"
my_test()
```

and this file is a executable file. And I have another python file in that file I am using commands to start my worker.py like this.

```
status, message = commands.getstatusoutput ("/tmp/worker.py")
```

but command can't go next level because of the raw_input.

Is there anyway I can pass "y" to worker through commands or subprocess ?.

PS : I am running this command through a pyqt gui.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE :

I found it at last and here is my solution, and yes its using pexpect.

fully working solution of my problem. I hope it will help some in else in future :)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import pexpect
import re
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Message box')
        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.spawnJob)
        self.qtxte = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(260, 150)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 340, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')
        self.show()

    def spawnJob(self):
        self.child = pexpect.spawn ('/usr/local/bin/python /tmp/worker.py')
        a = self.child.expect ('Do you')
        if str(self.child.after) == 'Do you':
            self.test_one()

       before_msg = self.child.before
           self.qtxte.appendPlainText(before_msg)

       for ln in self.child.readlines():
           self.qtxte.appendPlainText(ln.rstrip())

    def test_one(self):

        reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Message',
            "Are you sure to quit?", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes |
            QtGui.QMessageBox.No, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

        if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.child.sendline ('y')
        else:
            self.child.kill(0)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Take a look at pexpect (http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect).

Comment: thanks I will check this and a quick question, is it possible that i can use child.sendline at any point or it should pass when i am creating the object ?

Comment: the only issue I found with pexpect is after sendline i cant get the log, maybe I am wrong there will be some option.

Answer (score 1):

What about popen?  You can pass things to a process on stdin with that.

Or, you could try something like `"yes | /tmp/worker.py"` as your command.  `yes` just dumps a bunch of 'y' onto its stdout, which would then be picked up by worker.py.

Even simpler, use `"echo y | /tmp/worker.py"` as your command.  I just tried it, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks and this solution is cool, but the issue is i can't make "y" always, if user dont want to continue with the process then I want to send "n" to process . And another issue that I want to show the process logs to user then they can choose "y" or "n".

Comment: Oh, so the idea is that the process executes for a while, then the question is asked and you want to pass the question through to the user?

Comment: Use Popen, in the subprocess package.  The documentation is here: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen .  You can start the worker and watch for output on its stdout, then ask the user if they want to continue where necessary, and feed y or n back into its stdin.

Comment: yeah you are right I want to execute my process at a level then ask your for the next step. I tried with Popen and stdin but i never got successes with that :(

Comment: What do you mean by "i never got successes"?  It allows you to read the output of the subprocess, and write to the input to say yes or no

Comment: Did you use Popen, or call?  I've just tried Popen and both processes ran concurrently and I could use `child.stdout.readline()` to get any output coming from the child, and `child.stdin.write ('y')` to pass values to the child.